# ListView not working with SimpleCursorAdapter and ListAdapter

Tags: sqlite, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, listadapter

I know there are many questions similar to this and swear I have tried them all.
I am storing a string and database and want to retrieve it as list. This has been accomplished using `ListAdapter` (I followed a ToDo List Tutorial).

The issue is, I want to implement `OnItemClickListener` for this list that has been retrieved from DB. But the moment I replace `ListAdapter` with `ListView`, the app starts crashing with `NullPointException`.

Here is the code:

```
public class OfflineActivity extends ListActivity {
private ListAdapter listAdapter;
private TaskDBHelper helper;
ListView listView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.offline_list);
    updateUI();

}

private void updateUI() {
    helper = new TaskDBHelper(OfflineActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.offline_item,
            cursor,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
            new int[]{R.id.taskTextView},
            0
    );

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
}
```

The app works fine until I put `listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);` . Is there some way I can implement `OnItemClickListener`without making much changes in my code.?

Here are the XML files:

`offline_list.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

offline_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/taskTextView" />
```

PS. I am sure that `listAdapter` is not empty.. coz the `list` does get populated if I dont add the last line. stuck on it since 2 days. plssss help

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you declare a listView but you never assign a value to it.
You need to bind your listView to the layout before setting the adapter.

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: yup... sorry.. tried that as well.. but same `NullPointException` error

Answer (score 0):

As your `OfflineActivity` extends `ListActivity` and you have correctly given your `ListView` id as `@android:id/list` , you don't need to reference your `ListView` by `findViewById(R.id.list)` because it will be by referenced by default in the implementation of `ListActivity`. So no need for the two lines:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

In fact, `this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);` is attaching your adapter to your `ListView`.
For implementing OnClickListener for your List just overwrite the `onListItemClick()` of `ListActivity` as follows:

`OfflineActivity`

```
public class OfflineActivity extends ListActivity {
...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
}

@Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO implement your logic 
  }

}
```